# Spring boot - Whitelabel Error Page with HTML

Tags: html, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. I am trying to write Addition of two numbers using HTML and Spring Boot and I am getting below error. I am not getting where it's getting wrong. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Sep 29 14:16:06 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Sep 29 14:16:06 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Tried so many solutions but still not able to identify what is wrong.

Below is the code:

/templates/view.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

AddController.java

```
package com.springboot.swagger.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class AddController {

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    @ResponseBody
    public String courses(@RequestParam("t1") int i, @RequestParam("t2") int j) {
        
        return (i+j)+"";
    }
    
}
```

SpringBootApplication.java

```
package com.springboot.swagger;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.springboot"})
public class DemoAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=2080
logging.level.web=debug
logging.level.root=debug
```

Comment: How do you access view.html and where do you want to display the result of the addition?

Comment: When I run http://localhost:2080/view it should display text box for adding number and result should display.

Comment: Then you should learn Thymeleaf https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc

Comment: okay thanks for your suggestion! But What is wrong in the above code?

Comment: 1) The URL in the form is wrong. 2) You are using a RestController to submit a form to but then the result will not be handled. You must use a MVC Controller that returns the page you want to display